# What is the command to enable a .ini file in PHP like we do with Apache2 (i.e. equivalent to a2enconf for php)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, php

When one of my packages adds a new configuration file to Apache2, another package postinst script can enable it with a command such as:

```
a2enmod --quiet authz_host
```

*(The `--quiet` is useful to avoid warnings each time it is enabled again.)*

What is the equivalent for PHP .ini files?

I see I can install .ini files under `/etc/php/<version>/mods-available/` and these are linked in the `conf.d` folder. For example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 20  2022 10-mysqlnd.ini -> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
... (many other entries not shown here) ...
```

So I would imagine that there is a way to create this softlink using a PHP provided tool (i.e. I can always run an `ln -s ...` command, but how can I be sure I'm doing it correctly?).